# ReferralChasing with Native OLE DB/OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory

I know how to [query AD using SQL in SSIS by making an AD connection with the `Native OLE DB/OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services` provider](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1293.processing-active-directory-information-in-ssis.aspx).

What I cannot figure out is how to set the `ReferralChasing` property to `All`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted on the MSDN forums and learned that it is not possible to do this within SSIS.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c7f2b5b-77f0-460e-b637-c275ffa4550f/referralchasing-with-native-ole-dbole-db-provider-for-microsoft-directory-services-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices